# how to use a common data across action in a controller

Tags: cakephp

In my application am getting some values through webservice on the action index in controller.
I want to use the same data in other actions also. How to implement it without calling webservice again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the data in the session, see also the [sessions section](http://book.cakephp.org/view/173/Sessions) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->MyModel->findAll(); // or whatever your select looks like
$this->Session->write('myData',$data);
```

Then, in your other controller actions (irrespective of which specific controller you're using, provided they have the Session component turned on):

```
if($this->Session->check('myData')){
    $data = $this->Session->read('myData');
}
```

Now your data lives in `$data` and can be easily be sent to a view, etc.

For all of this to work, you're going to need to add this as a class-level variable to each controller where you'll want this data available:

```
var $components = array('Session');
```

Good luck!

Comment: You don't have to add the Session component to the $components array, it is automatically loaded.